# Can I use a 'known' Maclaurin series to find the sum of a given series if the series lower bound is not the same?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I'm having a bit of a dilemma right now and I thought I'd ask here. Pretty much, I have a list of known Maclaurin series that I can use on my exam and they greatly help me in solving series and their sums. However, I've encountered a bit different problem today. I have a series that in almost every aspect matches the one in the Maclaurin series list, with one difference: the lower bound of the series is $n=1$ as opposed to $n=0$ (the way it is written in the list). I'll give you the exact task I have as well:

The problem I need to solve (find the sum):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{4^{2n+1} (2n+1)!}$$
The Maclaurin series that I've found:
$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

I've tried doing it as if the lower bound was the same, and I get $\frac{1}{4}\sin(\pi)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{2n}}$

Can I do this? Does the lower bound matter in this situation?

Comment: You can always add and subtract a finite number of terms

Comment: @YuriyS does that mean I could just write $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n* \frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{4^{2n+1}*(2n+1)!} = (sin\pi-\pi)*\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n}$?

Comment: Are you able to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(\pi/4)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$? If yes, then your original problem can very easily be solved.

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{\pi ^{2n + 1} }}{{4^{2n + 1} (2n + 1)!}}}  =  - \frac{\pi }{4} + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{\pi ^{2n + 1} }}{{4^{2n + 1} (2n + 1)!}}}  =  - \frac{\pi }{4} + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{(\pi /4)^{2n + 1} }}{{(2n + 1)!}}}  \\=  - \frac{\pi }{4} + \sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{4}} \right),
$$ and in general $$
 - x + \sin x = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{x^{2n + 1} }}{{(2n + 1)!}}} ,
$$ i.e., you just remove the first term corresponding to $n=0$.

Comment: @Gary thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the lower bound matters, but in this case (as noted already in comments) you just have to subtract the first term in order to start the series one term later.

A bigger conceptual problem is that you seem to think that

$$
\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty f(n)g(n) \stackrel?=
\left(\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty f(n)\right)\left(\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty g(n)\right).
$$

This is not true in general.

Comment: Thank you, I sometimes get confused when it comes to series and their laws, but I'm working on it.